# How to compare values in 2 columns and do assignment in a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` named `data` as follows:

```
    id  upper_ci    lower_ci    max_power_contractual
0   12858 60.19878860406808 49.827481214215204  0
1   12858 60.61189293066522 49.298784196530896  0
2   12858 60.34397624424309 49.718421137642885  70
3   12858 59.87472261936114 49.464255779713476  10
4   12858 60.2735279368527  49.41672240525131   0
```

I am trying to create a new column named `up_threshold` as follows:

- If the value of `max_power_contractual` is either zero (`0`) or `NaN`, then the value in the `up_threshold` should be the value in the `upper_ci`
- If the value of `max_power_contractual` is not zero, and the condition: `max_power_contractual > upper_ci` is `True`, then the value in the `up_threshold` should be the value in the `upper_ci`
- If the value of `max_power_contractual < upper_ci` is `True`, then the value in the `up_threshold` should be the value in the `max_power_contractual`

I tried:

```
if (data['max_power_contractual'] in (0, np.nan)) or (data['max_power_contractual'] > data['upper_ci']):
    data['up_threshold'] = data['upper_ci']
elif (data['upper_ci'] > data['max_power_contractual'] == 0):
    data['up_threshold'] = data['max_power_contractual']
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/cortex/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py", line 179, in
>
> data = cp_detection(data, threshold)
>
> File "/home/cortex/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py", line 146, in
> cp_detection
> if data['max_power_contractual'] == 0:
>
> File
> "/home/cortex/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
> line 1479, in **nonzero**
> f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can someone please tell me my mistake and how can I solve it?

**Expected output:**

```
    id  upper_ci    lower_ci    max_power_contractual   up_threshold
0   12858 60.19878860406808 49.827481214215204  0   60.19878860406808 (Since `max_power_contractual` value is 0)
1   12858 60.61189293066522 49.298784196530896  NaN  60.61189293066522 (Since `max_power_contractual` value is NaN)
2   12858 60.34397624424309 49.718421137642885  70   60.34397624424309 (Since `upper_ci < max_power_contractual`)
3   12858 59.87472261936114 49.464255779713476  10  10 (Since `upper_ci > max_power_contractual`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.select`

```py
import numpy as np

m1 = df.max_power_contractual.isin([np.NaN, 0])
m2 = df.max_power_contractual > df.upper_ci

df['up_threshold'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df.upper_ci, df.upper_ci], default=df.max_power_contractual)
print(df)
```

Output

```
      id   upper_ci   lower_ci  max_power_contractual  up_threshold
0  12858  60.198789  49.827481                      0     60.198789
1  12858  60.611893  49.298784                      0     60.611893
2  12858  60.343976  49.718421                     70     60.343976
3  12858  59.874723  49.464256                     10     10.000000
4  12858  60.273528  49.416722                      0     60.273528
```

Since we're using the same columns as choices, we can also use

```py
df['up_threshold'] = np.where((m1 | m2), df.upper_ci, df.max_power_contractual)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where` to add the new column:

```
df['up_threshold'] = np.where(df['max_power_contractual'].fillna(0) == 0, df['upper_ci'],
    np.where(df['max_power_contractual'] > df['upper_ci'], df['upper_ci'], df['max_power_contractual'])
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      id   upper_ci   lower_ci  max_power_contractual  up_threshold
0  12858  60.198789  49.827481                    0.0     60.198789
1  12858  60.611893  49.298784                    NaN     60.611893
2  12858  60.343976  49.718421                   70.0     60.343976
3  12858  59.874723  49.464256                   10.0     10.000000
4  12858  60.273528  49.416722                    0.0     60.273528
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the efficient way but easier to understand

```
In [17]: def process(data):
    ...:     result = None
    ...:     if (data['max_power_contractual'] in (0, np.nan)) or (data['max_power_contractual'] > data['upper_ci']):
    ...:        result = data['upper_ci']
    ...:     elif (data['upper_ci'] > data['max_power_contractual']):
    ...:        result = data['max_power_contractual']
    ...:
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [18]: df.apply(process, axis=1)
Out[18]:
0    60.198789
1    60.611893
2    60.343976
3    10.000000
4    60.273528
dtype: float64

In [19]: df["up_threshold"] = df.apply(process, axis=1)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
      id   upper_ci   lower_ci  max_power_contractual  up_threshold
0  12858  60.198789  49.827481                      0     60.198789
1  12858  60.611893  49.298784                      0     60.611893
2  12858  60.343976  49.718421                     70     60.343976
3  12858  59.874723  49.464256                     10     10.000000
4  12858  60.273528  49.416722                      0     60.273528
```